# Training, Validation, and Testing Data in Supervised Learning

Tags: supervised-learning, beginner

I've come up with some simple definitions for training, testing and validation data in supervised learning. Can anyone verify/improve upon my answers?

**Training Data** - Used by the model to learn *parameters* and 'fit' to the data (usually involves multiple models fit at once) 
**Validation Data** - Used by the model to either a) determine the *best hyperparameter(s)* for a given model or b) determine the best performing model out of a given selection or c) determine the best hyperparameters of the best performing model out of a given selection (combining a and b) 
**Testing Data** - Used to gauge the final model performance (No further fitting is allowed at this point, so that we have an objective assessment of the model we've trained)

Comment: Overall correct. About validation data there is not much of "or" and "either". It is actually the third option which is model selection AND hyper parameter tuning. In the "Training" definition, I do not why it "usually involves multiple model to fit at once"! Do not bias yourself with that.

Comment: @KasraManshaei's comment is sound. In addition, validation data falls under the umbrella of [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) techniques, which, roughly speaking, prevents your model to overfit data.